# Odoo Enterprise Local Development

Tags: odoo, enterprise

How can I work with Odoo Enterprise on my localhost? Is that posible? Can I inherit a enterprise module and develop my own changes over it? If so... Is it like we do on community edition?
I have read about how to upgrade from community to enterprise edition on servers and how to install, deal with it but I have not a clear view if I can have a local instance when a buy a license and develop as normal. 
I am trying odoo12.
I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can very well upgrade your *Odoo community* to *Enterprise* version by buying the user license from Odoo.

You can customise any of the enterprise modules by inheriting them.

If you plan to upgrade to **Odoo 12 Enterprise** you must contact any of the Odoo partner company or Odoo to migrate your existing database to Odoo 12. They will migrate your database which would run on Odoo 12

Your existing custom modules can be converted to Odoo by any of the Odoo Partner companies or Odoo.

For Installing Odoo we have Two server options

1. Odoo.sh --> This is a cloud based platform which maintained by Odoo itself. It taskes automatic Backup everytoday. And the Domain name will be given by Odoo. You can have many instances like(Production, Staging, Testing)
   [Reference Link- Odoo SH configuration](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/configuring-using-odoosh/)
   [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gi13-XFvmCA)
2. Any other web hosting services like AWS, GoDaddy

Comment: Is there anyway to get the enterprise package for free?@sfx

Comment: But am I gonna develop and testing on my localhost as I do with community edition? How would I do that? Could I clone enterprise addons repository as I cloned community addons and then push my new or modified modules to any server instance that I decide to have? I am concerned about development environment specially if a enterprise paid module is envolved. I hope I have not to develop locally and can check what I have done when I push my changes on server.

Comment: Ady, You can clone the Enterprise addons to your local. After developing you can host it on any server. For development side you don't need any additional setup. You can continue using the same environment. But you need to upgrade your Python and libraries to V3.5 and above. PostgresSQL to 9.5 and above.

Comment: @Navi - You must have a Github account to clone the enterprise package for free